# NodeJS Socket.IO won't pass array to client

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I have encountered a problem where socket.emit will not send an array.

When the client receives it, it's just completely empty.

Server side:

```
var connectedUserNames = new Array() ;
socket.on('USER_ONLINE', function(data){
    connectedUserNames[socket.id] = data ;
    console.log(data+' has connected.') ;
})
io.sockets.emit('CONNECTED_USERS', connectedUserNames);
```

Client side:

```
socket.on('CONNECTED_USERS', function(data){alert(data);
    $('#connectedusers').attr('title', data) ;
})
```

Is this a bug with NodeJS? If so, how could I work around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your order seems very off there. You emit `CONNECTED_USERS` somewhere outside your `USER_ONLINE` event, so its most likely not filled with data. By the way, you declaring an `Array` but you access it like a plain object. If you don't need an indexed Array, you should just create a plain `Object`

```
var connectedUserNames = {};
```

or use `Array.prototype.push`, which is more convinient there

```
connectedUserNames.push( data );
```

Try to pull this line

```
io.sockets.emit('CONNECTED_USERS', connectedUserNames);
```

into your `USER_ONLINE` event and then make sure, your client actually fires that event at some point, so your server can react to that.